# How to detect filesystem type of un-mounted partition?

Tags: file-system, partitions

These commands won't work:

```
fdisk -l      #outputs nothing...
su; fdisk -l  #nothing..
sudo fdisk -l #sudo not found...
parted -l     #parted not found...
```

Is there any app that shows that easly?

EDIT:

For now I had to attach the sdcard to PC and let Linux mount it, I found the partition was `ext3` and not `ext2` that I thought! All I read says partition must be mounted to know its type. I think we must create a path and mount it with automatic detection and see mount output to know the partition type.

Comment: Related: [How do I find what type of file system is of an attached USB or SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220627/218526)

Answer (score 2):

Have you got the `file` command available? [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/328974/understanding-how-filesystem-type-is-determined-before-it-is-mounted) on SuperUser says that's the way to go.

Comment: very interesting, on my PC, this command: sudo file -Ls /dev/sda4; shows, without mounting, that the filesystem is ext4! but file command isnt available on my android :(, I have busybox, but no file command was found :(

Comment: mmm, seems we can have the file command: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=25264786, I just dont know if it will work on my android kernel