# How do I find what type of file system is of an attached USB or SD card?

Tags: file-system, formatting, usb-storage

How can I find the file system type of USB drive without using computer? Drive is attached to Android phone and I can see the files in it. I want to know if it is `extFAT` etc.

Answer (score 7):

Related question: [How to detect filesystem type of un-mounted partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43916)

Just to complete some missing pieces:

Usually we use `mount` command to see mounted filesystems, it works without root e.g. from a terminal emulator app or `adb shell`:

```
~$ mount
...
/dev/block/sda1 on /mnt/media_rw/C8BA-D0E2 type sdfat ...
/dev/block/sda2 on /mnt/media_rw/C78E-434F type vfat ...
/dev/block/sda3 on /mnt/media_rw/C81D-4E8D type vfat ...
```

It shows mounted filesystems on external USB drive to be `sdfat` and `vfat` which are **not actual filesystems but filesystem drivers**. A driver can support multiple filesystems and a filesystem can be mounted using different drivers. `sdfat` can be exFAT, FAT32 or FAT16. `vfat` can be one of latter two. Similarly filesystem types `sdcardfs`, `fuse` or `fusectl` aren't actual but virtual filesystems (FUSE can be used to mount any filesystem theoretically). So the output of `mount` command or apps like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) can be insufficient or misleading.

A more certain way is to read **filesystem magic** ([`file`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/filesystems) and [`blkid`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/master/libblkid/src/superblocks) commands do this). But the problem is that storage devices are enumerated as block devices by Linux/Android kernel and device nodes are created by Android `init`/`vold` with restricted permissions so that only root processes can access them (see [How to read ext4 filesystem without mounting on a non-rooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219926/218526)). So it's not possible to read partitions directly which hold filesystems inside them.

**With root access:**

```
~# blkid
/dev/block/sda1: ... TYPE="exfat"
```

```
~# file -s /dev/block/sda*
/dev/block/sda2: DOS/MBR boot sector ... FAT (32 bit)
/dev/block/sda3: DOS/MBR boot sector ... FAT (16 bit)
```

<sup>* Android's builtin `blkid` does have filesystem magic values but `toybox file` applet doesn't have. Use e.g. `file` on Termux which looks for a large magic database.</sup>

```
~# hexdump -C -n100 /dev/block/sda1 | grep -o '[EX]*FAT[0-9]*'
EXFAT
```

<sup>* [`hexdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) is a busybox applet.</sup>

exFAT magic is found at offset `3`, FAT32 at `82` and FAT12/FAT16 at `54`. So for **exFAT** `hexdump -e '"%_p"' -n5 -s3 /dev/block/sda1` returns `EXFAT`.

Similarly for **EXT4** `hexdump -e '"%X"' -n2 -s1080` should return `EF53` and for **F2FS** `hexdump -e '"%X"' -n4 -s1024` should return `F2F52010`.

**Without root access:**

Another option is to check `logcat` soon after boot or inserting USB drive or SD card. `vold` uses `blkid` at back end to detect filesystem before mounting which appears in log:

```
~$ adb logcat -v brief -s vold:V | grep TYPE=                                                                                                 
V/vold    (  752): /dev/block/vold/public:8,1: LABEL="disk" UUID="C8BA-D0E2" TYPE="exfat"
```

Comment: For adb logcat, if I run that command `C:\blah>adb logcat -v brief -s vold:V`  and I take out the SD card and put it back in.   I get this output  https://pastebin.com/raw/dt3zFb6L  which says within it. `/dev/block/vold/public:179,65: UUID="21FE-E026" TYPE="vfat"`  So still not so specific.  More specific than the mount command though that said sdcardfs!

Comment: By the way  you wrote "sdfat can be exFAT, FAT32 or FAT16. vfat can be one of latter two. ".   A google shows that vFAT can be FAT12, not just FAT16 or FAT32.  "The vFAT filesystem format is primarily used on older windows systems and portable USB drives or flash modules. It comes in three types FAT12 , FAT16 , and FAT32 all of which are supported by the vfat kernel module."

Answer (score 4):

Apps like [Disk Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) also provide the format (enable "show file system" in settings).

[image]

Comment: no, sdcardfs is a driver, not the actual thing(as answerer irfan mentions).  For an app showing file system on sd card, the other suggestion of devcheck  by answerer "fred", works

Answer (score 1):

The app [DevCheck](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.devcheck) will show you the actual filesystem of `/system` and `/sdcard`.  (unlike the "diskinfo" app).

Comment: if you see here this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqel.png  granted it doesn't say sdcardfs  which mount said and what diskinfo would probably have said  .  But it says vfat (which might be ab it more descriptive but still isn't the actual file system).     Irfan mentions "sdfat can be exFAT, FAT32 or FAT16. vfat can be one of latter two"