# How to fix mount errors when trying to mount the raw image that converted from android sparse image?

Tags: linux, mount, images, aosp, bind-mount

I have `sparse.img` image with the following properties:

```
$ file sparse.img 
sparse.img: Android sparse image, version: 1.0, Total of 2512896 4096-byte output blocks in 60 input chunks.
```

I want to see its contents so

- I have converted it into raw image.
- Created a new directory
- Trying to mount the raw image on to the directory

using the following commands:

```
$ simg2img sparse.img sparse_raw.img
$ mkdir raw
$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop sparse_raw.img raw
```

First two commands run fine and I can see `sparse_raw.img` generated of size larger than `sparse.img`.

Last command failed with an error:

> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop27, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I think that may be the `sparse_raw.img` is not an `ext4` image but how can I sure about it?

I have tried to mount it as

- ext2, ext3 or without -t
- without -o loop
  but nothing works.

Please suggest a way to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find what type of file system is of an attached USB or SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209347/how-do-i-find-what-type-of-file-system-is-of-an-attached-usb-or-sd-card)

Comment: `file sparse_raw.img` prints `data`. `hexdump -C -n1040 sparse_raw.img` prints `78 ba 2a 63 7a 05 50 ed ...` so it doesn't match with 10.20.f5.f2 or 53.ef.

Comment: @IrfanLatif The image is not mounted on any android system but it is available under file explorer of Ubuntu.

Comment: @VatishSharma I didn't say you need to mount the filesystem to see what filesystem it is. Checking filesystem is same irrespective of if it's a block device or a loop file; on Android or on Linux distro. Output of `file` and `hexdump` shows that it's not a filesystem. So mounting will definitely fail. Problem is with your `sparse.img` or `simg2img`, not with mounting.

Comment: I have other `sparse.img`s and they are working fine with `simg2img` and `mount` command but the one mentioned in the question and two more are not working. Any suggestions on how can I determine the problem?

Comment: @VatishSharma who created the `sparse.img`? Ask them what tool they used for sparseness and compression, and what filesystem it contains. It can be `ext4` or rarely `f2fs` (on `/system` or `/vendor`). Or `EROFS` in case of Huawei. Some vendors also experimented with `SquashFS`. Also use a different `simg2img` binary. Better build from latest source.

Comment: try this older build from fguy https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1054836&page=5

Comment: `sgs2toext4.jar` this worked instead of simg2img. Thank you guys for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file system might not be in the beginning of the raw partition image.

First you need to convert the image from sparse to raw, using either `simg2img` or [sparse_img_to_ext4.py](https://gist.github.com/Alex131089/bf51dcd70d96d4430d87451dec5ae6db).

Then, you need to find the beginning of the actual partition, [binwalk](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk) is my favorite tool for that:

```
$ binwalk super.raw.img

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1048576       0x100000        Linux EXT filesystem, rev 3.0, ext2 filesystem data, UUID=8f83745e-c212-5aab-a776-4aeed9fad9fa, volume name "/"
[...many many irrlevant hits...]
```

Now you can mount the file system using the first offset from the binwalk output:

```
sudo mount super.raw.img -t ext4 -o ro,loop,offset=0x100000 /media/super/
```

Answer (score 1):

The ext4 feature (400) is the new metadata_csum feature. If this feature is enabled and old tools are used to mount the filesystem they will only be able to mount read-only.

Try to mount it read-only:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o ro system.img.raw ~/mnt
```