# How can I copy files from an ext4 partition on my USB drive to a fat32 partition on the same drive?

Tags: root-access, usb, partitions, ext4

I tried mounting the ext4 partition as root, but it didn't work. My phone is rooted, but as it seems no one has managed to do what I want to do. I couldn't find any solution, that worked for me. How can I mount the ext4 partition?

What I have tried so far:

1. Manually mounting the partition. I tried running `mount -t ext4 /dev/block/sda2 /mnt/media_rw/usbotg`, but that doesn't work and outputs `mount: '/dev/block/sda2'->'/mnt/media_rw/usbotg': Invalid argument`. I was trying this, because of this answer - https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220020.
2. I also tried using `vold-posix`, but for some reason Magisk fails to install the module and shows `Unable to unpack boot image`, even though it is able to install Magisk updates on the boot image.

Comment: Please tell us explicitly what have you tried so far. And how it did *not work* for you. What error are you getting? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I added additional information.

Comment: `Invalid argument` is a general error. Run `strace mount` to get detailed log.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I couldn't copy everything, but here are the last lines, that I think might be relevant - https://pastebin.com/CS2FE1xS. (65F0-14E9 is my SD card)

Comment: I meant `strace mount -t ext4 /dev/block/sda2 /mnt/media_rw/usbotg`. Syscall tracing of the failing command.

Comment: @IrfanLatif This is the output - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neT8izdswtsGGBJ7Bqbg77KF9zEfGYip/view?usp=drivesdk. I couldn't upload it to pastebin.

Comment: It's pretty verbose: `mount("/dev/block/sda2", "/mnt/media_rw/usbotg", "ext4", MS_SILENT, NULL) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. First create directory: `mkdir /mnt/media_rw/usbotg`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif `mkdir: '/mnt/media_rw/usbotg/': File exists`. Oh it is a file. I will find a new directory then. Sorry.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I tried another directory and this one for sure exists. Here are the logs - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oyDmfJnnMxhAwyWI7jPgKOGCA-2FLrwS/view?usp=drivesdk. Also I wanted to say that the `usbotg` directory exists. It is for sure a directory. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Then `/dev/block/sda2` does not exist for sure. It looks like that you have just copied the command and you are not sure what you are doing. It's a dangerous practice. Please spend some time to familiarize yourself with commandline. Start with [`mount` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html).

Comment: @IrfanLatif I messed it up, but here is the final output - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pKpiEoJ18EwsT36uuGdrdho2FWnTfwwp/view?usp=drivesdk. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: Are you sure that `/dev/block/sda2` is an EXT4 filesystem? See [How do I find what type of file system is of an attached USB or SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220627/218526). Does `dd if=/dev/block/sda2 bs=1 skip=1080 count=2 status=none | xxd` show `53ef`? What happens if you do not provide filesystem (with `-t ext4`)?

Comment: @IrfanLatif The command returns `00000000: 53ef`. If I don't add `-t ext4` when mounting the partition, the output is `mount: /dev/block/sda2: need -t`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I found that the partition I was trying to mount had been corrupted by an app I used to shrink it. After formatting the partition it works flawlessly.