# On a not rooted smartphone, how do I format my SD Card to a file system of my choosing?

Tags: adb, external-sd, formatting

On a not rooted smartphone, how do I format my SD Card to a file system of my choosing?

Note that I have ordered an SD card reader so I can put my SD card into my laptop and try formatting it from there. But for now, without an SD card reader / without the ability to put the SD card into my laptop.

I can do

```
C:\Users\User>adb shell
ocean:/ $
```

I can even see the contents of the SD Card here

```
ocean:/sdcard $ ls
ls
Alarms  DCIM     Movies Notifications Podcasts  WhatsApp
Android Download Music  Pictures      Ringtones alt_autocycle
ocean:/sdcard $
```

I looked here [How do I find what type of file system is of an attached USB or SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209347/how-do-i-find-what-type-of-file-system-is-of-an-attached-usb-or-sd-card/248645#248645)  Currently it's showing as sdcardfs or more specifically vfat (which apparently is FAT12 or FAT16 or FAT32)

I'm interested in formatting it myself and choosing the specific file system.

Comment: search for usage of `newfs_msdos` `mkfs.exfat`

Comment: You can't. In my answer to the question you linked, I mentioned the reason: *"Storage devices are enumerated as block devices and device nodes are created with restricted permissions, so that **only root processes can access them**."*

Comment: right. I misread *"On a rooted smartphone"* ;)